# GKE Service (Loadbalancer) is not creating a loadbalancer properly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am creating the following service through a helm chart:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: nocode-x
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  creationTimestamp: "2023-12-15T14:06:44Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: kafka
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: nocode-x
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kafka
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 3.6.0
    helm.sh/chart: kafka-26.4.3
    pod: nocode-x-kafka-controller-0
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:finalizers:
          .: {}
          v:"service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup": {}
    manager: cloud-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    subresource: status
    time: "2023-12-15T14:06:44Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:meta.helm.sh/release-name: {}
          f:meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/component: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/instance: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/name: {}
          f:app.kubernetes.io/version: {}
          f:helm.sh/chart: {}
          f:pod: {}
      f:spec:
        f:allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: {}
        f:externalTrafficPolicy: {}
        f:internalTrafficPolicy: {}
        f:loadBalancerIP: {}
        f:ports:
          .: {}
          k:{"port":9095,"protocol":"TCP"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:port: {}
            f:protocol: {}
            f:targetPort: {}
        f:selector: {}
        f:sessionAffinity: {}
        f:type: {}
    manager: helm
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-12-15T14:06:44Z"
  name: nocode-x-kafka-controller-0-external
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "147938942"
  uid: 704cb5dc-c079-4ee3-b8c7-6335fbad90ea
spec:
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  clusterIP: 181.11.227.125
  clusterIPs:
  - 181.11.227.125
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  loadBalancerIP: 34.120.234.134
  ports:
  - name: tcp-kafka
    nodePort: 30484
    port: 9095
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: external
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller-eligible
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: nocode-x
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kafka
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kafka
    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: nocode-x-kafka-controller-0
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

However when I look at this service in the console i see the following:

[image]

And after I click on the link of the loadbalancer

[image]

I get the following error:

[image]

Something appears to be wrong with this loadbalancer. I have tried uninstalling/installing the same chart over and over but nothing seems to help (and the loadbalancer id appears to remain the same, so no new one is created).

Also good to mention, the service does not work, I cannot reach my workload by using the ipaddress connected to this service. I am guessing it has something todo with this loadbalancer not being created.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do not post images of error messages or any kind of text message. Copy and paste the message contents into your post.

Comment: These are not error messages or messages that one can simply copy and paste, but Okay I catch your drift. Have you any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are configuring a service load balancer by using a helm chart. This is just additional information that you can use to add a service load balancer and types of services through [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service#types-of-services)

For GKE service load balancer, you can manifest this yaml below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-gke-extlb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080 (use the port from container port)
  selector:
    app: hello-gke-extlb
```

Name and selector are an example coming from this [link](https://medium.com/google-cloud/deploying-service-or-ingress-on-gke-59a49b134e3b) wherein the service is just exposing the Deployment applied.

Let me also share this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/ip-addresses#regional_and_global_ip_addresses) just to differentiate the Regional and Global IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by deleting the static ip address in gcp and creating a new one & then use this new ip-address in my service.

I guess it had something todo with the old ip-address being a global and not a regional ip address...

Anyway I would expect a decent error message that a loadbalancer could not be created because the correct static ip-address could not be found.